# Multiplying a matrix by a plane

Tags: matrices

I have a question - make a sketch showing the effect of multiplication by the matrix

$A=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}$ on the plane $\Bbb R^2$.

How do you multiply a matrix by a plane?? Does it have to do with linear transformations?

Thanks!

Comment: You aren't meant to multiply the whole plane by the matrix; you're meant to show what that matrix does to elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Try showing where it maps the unit vectors $\vec{i}$ and $\vec{j}$, and also $\vec{i} + \vec{j}$. Showing the image of the unit square under a linear map is a standard way to show what that map does. And yes, a function defined by matrix multiplication of scalars is a linear transformation.

Comment: Matrix and plane are different objects. Please give your definition of multiplying a matrix by a plane.

Comment: I agree with Eric. Look at the animated GIF on the [Wikipedia's SVD page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition). You're not expected to make a movie like that, but it should give you an idea.

Comment: Ok. So what I've done is multiply the matrix by a unit square with coordinates (1,1),(2,1),(1,2),(2,2) and obtained a parallelogram (the unit square dilated by a factor of 2*Sqrt(2) and rotated counterclockwise by 45 degrees) with coordinates (1,5),(3,7),(0,8),(2,10). And it makes the unit vector i-hat into sqrt(2)i-hat + sqrt(2)j-hat, and it makes the unit vector j-hat into -1(i-hat)+3(j-hat). It makes the vector (i-hat+j-hat) into (i-hat)+5(j-hat). Are all my calculations correct? Also, is this a complete set of tests for multiplication by R2, or should I do more? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand my comment slightly into an answer: you aren't intended to multiply the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ by your matrix $A$; indeed, that doesn't even make sense. What the exercise intends is for you to show what multiplication by the matrix $A$ does to elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

The standard way to do this is to show the image under $A$ of the vectors $\vec{i}$, $\vec{j}$, and $\vec{i} + \vec{j}$. Computing this, we find that
$$A\vec{i} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix},$$
$$A\vec{j} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix},$$
$$A(\vec{i}+\vec{j}) = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 5 \end{bmatrix}.$$

$\hskip2in$ [image: image of input and output vectors]

Your calculations are correct, but it's easier to use the unit square containing the vertices (0,0), (1,0), (0,1), (1,1); zeros always make life easier.